# How can I get ErrorDocument in .htaccess to output wrong uri parameter?

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, errordocument

I've worked-around the solution to transform all uri to one page via ErrorDocument.

The reason behind this is to send Files AND folders (nice urls) to one page. However, I need the URI string to be sent to index.php?uri=string  . Is this possible via ErrorDocument, or how do I do this?

So I need to rewrite the

> http://www.something.com/games/specific-game

to

> http://www.something.com/index.php?uri=/games/specific-game

Is this possible at all, if, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server supports server-side include (SSI) then you use the following `404.shtml` as your ErrorDocument:

```
<html>
<header>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=/index.php?uri=<!--#echo var="REQUEST_URI" -->">
</header>
</html>
```

EDIT: there is a simpler way: create a PHP file as your ErrorDocument and you can do anything under the sun in it! :)

EDIT2: you can access the original URI using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

EDIT3: heck, if you are just redirecting to `index.php` on the same host, you can just set that `index.php` file as your ErrorDocument and detect if the request is redirected from 404 error by checking if `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'] == '404'`

Comment: yees, but .. I need to get that URI the user entered and was incorrect.. is that sent as variable to such php ErrorDocument then?

Comment: new info: it does not work, because it's redirected to this index.php?uri=<!--#echo var=  AND there is not URI in the parameter.

Comment: meaning your server doesn't support SSI then .. just use PHP then. you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to access the original URI.