# Apache .htaccess 404 error redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to make an htaccess file that will redirect all 404 errors through index.php. I would like the page the user failed to access to be appended to index.php's URL so that I can find out what page request failed.

For example, if they tried to access http://example.com/doesntexist.php, apache should redirect them to http://example.com/index.php/doesntexist

This is what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

This works on one of my webhosts but failed when I transfered the site to another webhost (GoDaddy).

Thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't test this right now, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048888/how-can-i-get-errordocument-in-htaccess-to-output-wrong-uri-parameter), when you set a

```
ErrorDocument /404.php
```

(or index.php, doesn't matter)

The `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` variable will contain the original, failed request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution works fine, but I may have mis-worded my question. I do not want Apache to send a 404 header with the page. This is why I was using the Rewrite Conditions. How can I make a htaccess with the same effect that "ErrorDocument /404.php" produces, except without the 404 header?

Comment: @Nathan ah! Hm, that may be tough. PHP has [`header_remove()`](http://www.php.net/header_remove) but it doesn't seem to remove headers previously set by Apache. Are you sure GoDaddy has URL rewriting enabled at all?

Answer (score 2):

A side note from the direct solution, as this prevented the proper ErrorDocument redirection to work. Hope this serves as a reference for anyone which happened to stumbled on the same error as mine.

I have created an .htaccess and put

```
ErrorDocument 404 /Error/404.html
```

But the redirect never work and the default Not Found page was shown instead.
The problem is actually lies in the setting in apache2.conf (or httpd.conf).

Removing line below immediately solved the problem

```
AllowOverride None
```

It prohibits the .htaccess from overriding the default setting.