# How do I redirect a URL that isn't found without sending a 404 header?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My website needs a `.htaccess` file that will redirect a user to `index.php` when a page is not found. However, I do not want Apache to send a 404 header with the document.

I asked this question earlier:
[Apache .htaccess 404 error redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173266/apache-htaccess-redirect)

The command `"ErrorDocument /index.php"` produces the exact effect that I want, except that it sends a 404 header with the page. What can I do? Should I overwrite the 404 header with PHP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

1. enable rewrite
2. check if requested file exists as a regualar file with size (not empty)
3. check if requested file is link
4. check if requested file is a directory
5. if one of the previous 3 statements is true show that file
6. otherwise go to index.php

If the redirect to index.php happens u can get the requested uri by using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` inside `index.php`

> - '-d' (is directory) Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests if
>     it exists and is a directory.
> - '-f' (is regular file) Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests if
>     it exists and is a regular file.
> - '-s' (is regular file with size) Treats the TestString as a pathname
>     and tests if it exists and is a
>     regular file with size greater than
>     zero.
> - '-l' (is symbolic link) Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests if
>     it exists and is a symbolic link.
> - '-F' (is existing file via subrequest) Checks if TestString is a
>     valid file and accessible via all the
>     server's currently-configured access
>     controls for that path. This uses an
>     internal subrequest to determine the
>     check, so use it with care because it
>     decreases your servers performance!
> - '-U' (is existing URL via subrequest) Checks if TestString is a
>     valid URL and accessible via all the
>     server's currently-configured access
>     controls for that path. This uses an
>     internal subrequest to determine the
>     check, so use it with care because it
>     decreases your server's performance!

More information: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thank you for such an in depth answer. I couldn't find a good htaccess tutorial - your answer explains everything I was looking for very clearly.