# Prevent Apache 2 to search for /index

Tags: apache, indexing

I have a problem with my apache 2 configuration. If I run

```
http://myhost.com/user/search
```

Everything works fine. My website loads perfectly. But if I run

```
http://myhost.com/index
```

I get a 404 error. Is it possible to prevent this?

I thank you for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190206/apache-htaccess-how-do-i-redirect-for-files-that-arent-found-without-sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include the following, and replace `index.html`with any page you want the visiter to land on:
`ErrorDocument 404 /index.html`