# PHP search & replace img src

Tags: php, jquery, image, search, replace

Ok, the situation is simple (i hope!)

I am working locally (xampp) and in my .php file i've got the following img elements :

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/project-1/image1.jpg"/>
<img src="http://example.com/images/project-1/image2.jpg" />
<img src="http://example.com/images/project-1/image3.jpg" />
```

How can I make it to run a search and replace function (with php if possible) that will fulfil the following:

1) On page load to scan the whole document and find all the above images that don't appear (broken links)

2) **IF** from the above we find broken images , then to replace **only** the part that says "http://example.com" with "http://127.0.0.1/projectfile".

So what I want is to scan the whole document for broken images and if I find x of them then to replace the src from this:

src="http://www.example.com/images/project-1/image1.jpg"

with this:

src="http://127.0.0.1/project/images/project-1/image1.jpg"

I want to do this for all the images automatic, and not manually.

Currently I am struggling to do this with jQuery but I probably I am gonna need PHP because I need to navigate to the previous folders,scan dir etc etc

Thank you for you support!
Any ideas or tips?

So far what I tried and succeeded partially as I said above is to search/replace with jQuery:

```
$('img').attr('src',function(i,e){
    return e.replace("http://example.com","http://127.0.0.1");
})
```

,which ignores the live website src folder and sticks directly to the local folder but I need to make it a bit more clever :)

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this? The reason makes it clearer if you should use server-side (php) or clientside (javascript/jquery)

Comment: I would consider using .htaccess for this - if it is an Apache server. It would very clearly and fast and automatically redirect to the existing image if the link doesn't end at the real file. See this (of course you need some changes to make it work with image files etc..): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190206/apache-htaccess-how-do-i-redirect-for-files-that-arent-found-without-sending

Comment: How are the images created? Is it possible to check if they exist and replace when they are created?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your swift reply!

The reason I want to do this is because I am working on a live website right now with lots of pages and also lots of broken image-links.

All the img src from the live files are relevant "/images/something/image.jpg" and because I have to work offline (uploading new images on the server is a pain..long story..) I want to make sure somehow that my offline file will be able to "drag" the live images from the live website first, and if not then i should create a subdirectory/filepath offline (and later online) with the new image file that needs to be put there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery error event to detect missing images and replace them. Following code should do the trick

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').on('error',function(){
    // Avoid endless loop for noexistant images
    if($(this).data('alreadyChecked')) return; 
    $(this).data('alreadyChecked',true);
    
    //Replace src
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace("http://example.com","http://127.0.0.1"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://example.com/images/project-1/image1.jpg"/>
<img src="http://example.com/images/project-1/image2.jpg" />
<img src="http://example.com/images/project-1/image3.jpg" />
```

Comment: Also add a property to the image so that if the replaced image is also non-existent, it shouldn't get caught in a loop. E.g in plain js `if (this.checked == undefined) {
                 this.checked = 1; 
                 this.src = this.src.replace("http://example.com","http://127.0.0.1");
             }`

Comment: that did the trick!!!!

I am having problems though to do the same for the background-images (css)!

I tried the 

$(this).css('background').replace("http://example.com", "http://127.0.0.1") 

but nothing happens :(

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what you want is to use javascript/jquery and replace the href value when the condition (broken link) is met.

Comment: Any ideas on how I am going to achieve this? Currently I can only find ways to replace the whole img src path with a fixed path ("path/to/sorry-image-is-broken.jpg" ) but not to search and replace partially the img-src

Comment: you can split the href value like this $('.myTargetClass').attr('href').split('/')

Answer (score 0):

A solution with .htaccess is the best approach for this.  PHP wont do it because PHP executes **before** the page loads.  By the time these elements are on your page, it's already too late for PHP to touch them.  I'm sure a hack with jQuery could work on this but it wont be reliable and it will slow down your loads and you will likely have flicker because jQuery can't touch the items until after the page loads, and at that point your broken links will already be showing until jQuery replaces them.

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$
RewriteRule ^.*/images/(.*)/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/project/images/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

.htaccess will replace the URLs at the request level before PHP or jQuery ever even see the content.

Comment: This can be a solution if the OP has all the images coming from their own server.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys!!
Although I was initially looking for a PHP way to do this, apparently JQuery worked as well!

Thanks @Nadeem Manzoor and the rest! :)