# Overriding httpd/apache upstream proxy httpcode with another

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform, proxy

I have some react code (written by someone else) that needs to be served. The preferred method is via a Google Storage Bucket, fronted by their Cloud CDN, and this works. However, due to some quirks in the code, there is a requirement to override 404s with 200s, and serve content from the homepage instead (i.e. if there is a 404, don't serve a 404, serve the content of the homepage and return as a 200 instead)

(If anyone is interested, this override currently is implemented in CloudFront on AWS. Google CDN does not provide this functionality yet)

So, if the code is served at "www.mysite.com/app/" and someone hits "www.mysite.com/app/not-here" (which would return a 404), what should happen is that the response should NOT be 404, but a 200 with the content being served from `index.html` instead.

I was able to get this working by bundling all the code inside a docker container and then using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190206/how-do-i-redirect-a-url-that-isnt-found-without-sending-a-404-header/5190782#5190782). However, this setup means if we have a code change, all the running containers need to be restarted, and the customer expects zero downtime, hence the bucket solution.

So I now need to do the same thing but with the files being proxied in (with the upstream being the CDN).

I cannot use the original solution since the files are no longer local, and httpd can't check for existence of something that is not local.

I've tried things like `ProxyErrorOverride` and `ErrorDocument`, and managed to get it to redirect, but that is not what is needed.

Does anyone know how/if this can be done?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why all the container must be restarted? You are talking of which containers? In addition, do you want to serve the solution directly from Cloud Storage? Or do you want to build something around your static code (a container for instance) and to serve it?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere: The docker image uses httpd as a proxy so we can route specific paths to the bucket and serve other paths through a different backend. 

However, using this method, we cannot find a way to override the bucket 404s (that's this question.)

If we "bake in" the bucket files into the image, we can override the 404s by checking for file existence (the solution I linked in the original post), and not need to proxy to the bucket. But on code change, the image then needs to be rebuilt and rolled out, hence the restart. 

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is: how to catch the 404 error provided by Cloud Storage when a file is missing with httpd/apache? I don't know.

However, I think that isn't the best solution. Serving files directly from Cloud Storage is convenient but not industrial.

Imagine, you deploy several broken files successively, how to rollback in a stable format?

The best is to package your different code release in an atomic bag, a container for instance. Each version are in a different container and performing a rollback is easier and consistent.

---

Now your "container restart" issue. I don't know on which platform you are running your container. If your run it on a Compute Engine (a VM) it's maybe the worse solution. Today, there is container orchestration system that allows you to deploy, scale up and down the containers, and to perform progressive rollout, to replace, without downtime, the existing running containers by a newer version.

Cloud Run is a wonderful serverless solution for that, you also have Kubernetes (GKE on Google Cloud) that you can use with Knative for a better developer experience.

Comment: To answer your first question, several successive missing files is expected for the app and it should respond as described -- with a 200 and the contents of the homepage (don't ask, I didn't write the app, but the devs insist that this is correct)

Comment: To answer your question about the container restart: the current version of the code runs in AWS ECS and we're trying to move it to Kubernetes GKE with Cloud CDN instead of CloudFront. CloudFront provides an http code override option, but Cloud CDN doesn't (which is why we are in this situation, looking for alternative solutions to provide that functionality that exists in AWS but does not exist on GCP).

Comment: My recommendation: for frontend resource serving, forget GKE, use Cloud Run isntead