# .htaccess ErrorDocument Redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, relative-path

I am very new to Apache and .htaccess, and I had a simple question regarding how to handle 403 and 404 errors with Apache's ErrorDocument command.

Let's look at this code from an early CMS I wrote:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /admin/includes/access_deny.php?error=404
```

This will silently redirect the user to `http://www.mysite.com/admin/includes/access_deny.php?error=404` when they get a 404 error.

Here is my problem, this error document will always be in the same place, with regards to the .htaccess file. However, if I need to move my installation, say to the directory `subfolder`, I will need to open the .htaccess file an update the to following, for it to work correctly:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /subfolder/admin/includes/access_deny.php?error=404
```

Is there a way I can have .htaccess redirect to this page `admin/includes/access_deny.php?error=404` in regards to the file itself, not an absolute URL? Also, no matter where I would move the installation in the future, Apache will catch all 404 errors that are on the same level or sub-directories to this file.

Please let me know if that is not clear.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument):

URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which the client can resolve. Alternatively, a message can be provided to be displayed by the browser.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173266/apache-htaccess-redirect) may help you fix it though.

Comment: ok, so *everything* has to be relative to the doc root. no wonder no one had the answer I was hoping :) Thanks, pritaeas!